# How to instal in SVN repository on local Machine

Tags: svn, installation

How to instal in SVN repository server 
on Windows local Machine.?

Comment: what OS? => reading the manual might clue you in? look at http://subversion.apache.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Official Installation Guide](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL)

Answer (score 2):

If its a windows system, you could use VisualSVN Server (http://www.visualsvn.com/). Fairly automated, and not too tricky.

Also, if you use Microsoft Visual Studio, you can download a sister plugin that lets you perform normal SVN instructions through.